# .NET Core 2.2 Receiving 401 Unauthorized response when calling IIS site on same server with Windows Auth

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, windows-authentication, .net-core-2.2

I'm having some strange behavior in my .NET Core 2.2 application.

When trying to make an HTTP request (through either HttpClient or RestSharp), as long as the site that I am requesting is hosted on a *different* server than where my calling application resides, I receive a 200 response, just like I'd expect, which is great.

However, as soon as I try to hit a site on the same server (and I've tried this with the exact same site hosted on both servers), I get a 401 Unauthorized.

For reference, the site that I am requesting is a ASP.NET Web API on .Net Framework, and it uses Windows Auth.

I've tried this in .Net Framework 4.6.2 and .Net Core 3.0, and both of them work fine, and do not exhibit this problem -- it seems just to affect 2.2 for me.

I know there is the ["Loopback Check Issue"](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx), however if this was the case, I'd expect .Net Framework and .Net Core 3.0 to face the same problem.

I also am aware of [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25988) however that seems to have been solved in 2.2.

For reference here is some sample code that demonstrates the problem with HttpClient (The same codes is used for all versions of .Net)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await MakeRequest();
    }
    public async static Task MakeRequest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter URL:");
        var url = Console.ReadLine();
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
            var res = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(res.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e}");
        }
        finally
        {
            await MakeRequest();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
SDK used: 2.2.104

Runtime used: 2.2.5

Comment: What .NET runtime sdk are you using? I tried both 2.2.1 and 2.2.4. Both of them works fine with runtime 2.2.7. I also tried both Kerberos and ntlm authentication. This issue is really strange.

Comment: I should have mentioned that!  Running .net core 2.2.5 on the server.

Answer (score 0):

2.2.5 seems to be the version of .NET core runtime version instead of .NET CORE SDK version.

The latest version of 2.2 sdk is 2.2.4.

Since 2.2.7 would be the update verion of 2.2.5 and this issue is not happening in runtime 2.2.7. Is it acceptable to just update runtime 2.2.7 on your server?

Comment: Sorry about that -- the runtime is 2.2.5, I've tried SDK versions 2.2.104, so certainly  not the latest version.  Is there a known issue for this?